# Creating a foreign key on string constraint in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have two poorly designed tables in a MySQL database. These tables holds very long strings.

In `table1` the field `unqiue_string_1` is unqiue:

```
table1
unique_string_1 | long_string_1 | long_string | ..
```

And in `table2` the field `unqiue_string_1` is not unique.

```
table2
unique_string_1 | .. | more strings..
------------------------------------------
sample_string_1 | .. | more strings..
sample_string_1 | .. | more strings..
sample_string_1 | .. | more strings..
sample_string_3 | .. | more strings..
sample_string_3 | .. | more strings..
sample_string_3 | .. | more strings..
sample_string_4 | .. | more strings..
sample_string_4 | .. | more strings..
```

Right now my phpMyAdmin connection times out when I try to retrieve large datasets. I want to make queries a bit faster by indexing things and making foreign key relations.

First I did this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_id ON table1(unqiue_string_1)
```

Now I want a SQL statement to create the foreign key. I have tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE table2
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`my_id`)
REFERENCES table(`my_id`);
```

I think I am missing some kind of constraint so that `sample_string_1` has a foreign key in `table2` equal to index in `table1`. What am I missing?

Comment: How long are the strings?

Comment: They are around 50 chars. There are a few thousands unique strings, however, making `table2` longer than 100.000 rows. Thanks for the fast reply!

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax you want is:

```
ALTER TABLE table2
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (`unique_string_1`) REFERENCES table1(`unique_string_1`);
```

The references are to the column name, not the index.

Comment: Okay. And in this case I do not even need the `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_id ON table1(unqiue_string_1)` statement then?

Comment: If is unique, you should declare it as unique.  MySQL requires an index on the field, and a unique index is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

The small mistake is in the REFERENCES table: Table should be a table name:

```
ALTER TABLE table2
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`unique_string_1`) REFERENCES table1(`unique_string_1`);
```